# Why Xcode says that 'instance will be immediately deallocated'?

Tags: appdelegate, swift-protocols

I'm trying to find out why am I getting the following message in Xcode:

```
Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'delegate' is 'weak'
```

Here's a code:

```swift
import ARKit
     
class OtherViewController: NSObject, ARSCNViewDelegate { }
    
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
        
    var arView = ARSCNView(frame: .zero)
    let otherVC = OtherViewController()
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // I'M USING ONE OF THESE
        
        arView.delegate = self                // works fine
        arView.delegate = otherVC             // works fine
        arView.delegate = ViewController()    // PRINTS WARNING
    }
}
```

Question:

I understand that the delegate is a `weak` and optional:

```swift
weak var delegate: ARSCNViewDelegate? { get set }
```

However, why `arView.delegate = self` or `arView.delegate = otherVC` works FINE but `arView.delegate = ViewController()` prints a warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting arView.delegate = ViewController() you’re creating a new instance of ViewController that isn’t retained anywhere so it’s deallocated as soon as the function returns.

Comment: so, what is the solution if we need to do this kind of stuff ?